# pushViewController doesn't work when app is in background?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I recently refactored an app to use a `UINavigationController` and `pushViewController(...)` to transition back and forth between the main UIViewControllers of my app. Previously I was using `present(...)` with no issues. The app is a music player and has the appropriate background mode.

The transition to view controller **B** from view controller **A** happens after a 5 second countdown and thus can happen in the background if the user hits their home button or turns the screen off.

The issue is that the push, and all relevant events that are supposed to kick off when the view did appear, **do not fire while the app is in the background**, and immediately fire as soon as I turn the display back on or bring the app into the foreground.

Is there any way to force the push to happen even if the app isn't visible, or a different method to push and display the view controller?

Thank for any insight!

```
let nav = self.parent as! UINavigationController
print("Attempting to .pushViewController...")
nav.pushViewController(sessionVC, animated: false)
print("After .pushViewController...")
```

Comment: You can subscribe for applicationDidEnterBackground(_:) and applicationDidBecomeActive(_:) notifications. Have two boolean variables  say isInBackground and transitionBack in your ViewController and when you get notified of didEnterBackground, set your boolean to true and when you countdown ends check for the boolean and if its true postpone the transition, transitionBack to true and wait for didbecomeactive notification and check of transitionBack. if its true do the Push stuff

Comment: @Eric R, did you find any solution?